# useSelector behaves differently on Firefox and Chrome

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser, react-hooks, frontend

This code works on chrome and fails in firefox:

```
const loginCredentials = useSelector(state => state.login.state.loginCredentials) || {};
```

I am getting the following error on firefox:

```
state.login.state is undefined
```

So, why do you think it is behaving like this?

Comment: Can you confirm `state.login.state.loginCredentials` is correct and it is not supposed to be `state.login.loginCredentials`, please?

Comment: It is valid and works in Chrome.